# Update Windows Installer without reboot

Tags: windows-xp, updates, windows-installer

I need to update Windows Installer to 4.5 on Windows XP (Hotfix KB942288) but it has to be done without a reboot. Some software we're trying to install requires WI 4.5 but it's on a computer that cannot be restarted. It runs on a multi-site HA VMWare ESX cluster and we need to keep it as close to 100% uptime as possible (Our SLA is 6 nines), the services it's running don't support Windows Server or their own HA/clustering so we must keep a single instance up all the time. We can't even run security updates.

Is there any way to get the WI 4.5 update fully installed without a full reboot?

Post;
I **know** nothing that needs 6 nines uptime should be run on a single instance, but the software doesn't support any form of clustering, failover, replication, HA etc. I've never had anything to do with this server before (I'm actually a UNIX sysadmin but I've been pulled onto this for some reason unknown to me).

Comment: Name and shame the security auditor and then I will help you :P ... (Joke) attempting to write the answer now...

Comment: Argh, just tested in a VM, can't see an easy away around it requiring a restart - sorry :(

Comment: Pulling a UNIX IT tech over to Windows? sounds like a fall guy to me. The Unix guy screwed it up, your fired!

Comment: In short, no, some updates modify parts of the registry that require a restart, no way around this, its WINDOWS not Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will fully answer your question because I believe you eventually will have to restart the service if not the server. If you had the /norestart option to the execution of the package it will suppress the reboot, and will either return ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED or ERROR_SUCCESS. You will most likely have to shut down the Windows Installer service. Check this page for more details [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372856%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)